# Javascript calling C# function under Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, function

I have a Silverlight application using C#, with 2 main functions that I want to make accessible from JavaScript functions.  I have done the RegisterScriptableObject() in the class and set-up the [ScriptableMember] for the functions I want access to.

This the Silverlight object:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object id="silverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="1024px" height="300px">
        <param name="source" value="DrawingWaveForm.xap"/>
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe>
</div>
```

and these are my JavaScript functions:

```
    function Start()
    {
        var control = document.getElementById("silverlightControl");            
        control.Content.Page.Start();
    }

    function Stop()
    {
        var control = document.getElementById("silverlightControl");            
        control.Content.Page.Stop();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong as it does not seem to work

Comment: i get the following error message:
Error: uncaught exception: Error setting property on scriptable plugin object! [plugin exception: Object doesn't support this property or method].

Comment: Would it be the same problem that was answered at this link?
[Javascript to Silverlight when Silverlight instanciated with object tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639862/javascript-to-silverlight-when-silverlight-instanciated-with-object-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As timheuer said, [Scriptable] on your Silverlight methods.

Call this in your class:

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
```

Call the Silverlight methods marked as Scriptable from your javascript like this:

```
function CenterMap(latitude, longitude)
{
     var silvercontrol = document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMain_slControl");
     if (silvercontrol)
     silvercontrol.Content.Page.CenterOnCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
}
```

[This page](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/archive/2008/05/15/call-silverlight-from-javascript-call-javascript-from-silverlight.aspx) shows you this and how to do the reverse, calling javascript methods from Silverlight. It's a really nice model.

Comment: Ignore the dirty hardcoded control id there :p a nice ends with works fine.  var silverlightControl = $("[id $='slControl']");

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your C# functions are marked as Scriptable.  See http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=65683 for some walk throughs on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I've done that, added [ScriptableMember] above both functions, but still get the message:  Error: uncaught exception: Error setting property on scriptable plugin object! [plugin exception: Object doesn't support this property or method].

Answer (score 0):

It's just a thought but do you perhaps need to make the methods public (they don't appear to be in your code)?

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work, actually, it stopped my other functions working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was just hammering against this problem myself. The first js function works, but everything else throws this error. After tinkering around, I noticed that changing the underlying C# function that was working successfully was having no impact -- the browser was working with a cached version of the Silverlight control. Try clearing your browser's cache.